# Avoiding page break in pdf generation with salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I must remove page break while generating pdf by visual force pdf, but whatever I try with css `page-break-inside: avoid;`, `page-break-before: avoid;` etc. is not working.

I want to remove all page breaks making it a continuous pdf page, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: whats the api version of your visualforce?can we get whole code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CSS styling for the APEX component, try a div tag around the APEX components you want to not be broken apart with style="page-break-inside:avoid;"

//div style="width:100%;page-break-inside:avoid;"> APEX  ///div>

Answer (score 0):

This `css  page-break-inside: avoid;, page-break-before: avoid;` works only when you need to iterate on components. If you are using inline pre-built css into page then you have to check following css related to body tag. like this:

```
body { box-sizing: border-box; height: 11in; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; padding: 0.5in; width: 8.5in; }
```

Here I am using width and height with auto value.